# Excel - allow result to change if value is greater than

Tags: excel, if-statement

my first post here and I am no expert to say the least. I have been using this simple excel sheet I created years ago with no issues. I now want to have a new price for sandblasting anything that goes past 1200 in length. On my screenshot E9 calculates the size of the product by multiplying C9 and D9 and the result goes in E9. In F9 I need the result of the price to be different if the size goes past 1200 in either C9 or D9. When I make the D9 value 1201, I need it to take the rate at which it prices the product from box E4 instead of E3. When I make the size go past 1201, it does use the different rate from E4 but it just puts that £77 figure in and does not multiply the result by the £77. This is almost working but it needs to multiply the E9 box by the E4 box if either C3 or D3 have gone past the 1200 value but it isn’t doing that. Can anyone help please?

You can see the code I am trying to use for F9 in the screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaQlN.png)

Comment: =if(or(c9>1200,D9>1200),E4,E3)

Comment: `=IF(OR(C9>1200,D9>1200),E$4,E$3)*E9`

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(OR(C9>1200,D9>1200),E9*E$4,E9*E$3)`

This will check if C9 or D9 is above 1200. If either (or both) of those numbers are bigger than 1200, it will multiple E9 by E4. If neither of them are above 1200, it will multiple E9 by E3.

This is for cell F9 but you can drag it down to further rows and it will still work.